# xml values are not passed to detalview for iphone

Tags: iphone, xml

Somehow its data is not transferring so I am using other method for displaying but is this good for memory management ??

```
if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"telnumber"]) {

   NSLog(@"Processing Value: %@", currentElementValue);
   NSUserDefaults *tel = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   [tel setObject:currentElementValue forKey:@"keyTotel"];
   return;
}
```

and then in detail view i am using this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"String = %@",aBook.telnumber);
    NSUserDefaults *get = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *mytel = [get stringForKey:@"keyTotel"];
    NSLog(@" LOCAL phone   is %@",mytel); 
}
```

So for all 6 elements on XML I have to follow same process is that good enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) :

> The NSUserDefaults class provides a programmatic interface for interacting with the defaults system. The defaults system allows an application to customize its behavior to match a user’s preferences. For example, you can allow users to determine what units of measurement your application displays or how often documents are automatically saved. Applications record such preferences by assigning values to a set of parameters in a user’s defaults database. The parameters are referred to as defaults since they’re commonly used to determine an application’s default state at startup or the way it acts by default

So, you shouldn't really be using `NSUserDefaults` to hold anything other than default application settings (and certainly not for holding temporary variables).

I assume you are parsing your XML file at some point in the application, prior to the `UITableView` appearing?

A better (simple) approach would be to have another class that represents the object being described in the XML, and populating this object with the data extracted from the XML. (or populate n objects for n entries in the xml).

So, if your XML describes a contact in your app:
**HumanContact.h**

```
@interface HumanContact : NSObject {
NSString* firstName;
NSString* surname;
NSString* telephoneNumber;
//etc...

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* firstName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* surname;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* telephoneNumber;
```

**HumanContact.m**

```
#import "HumanContact.h"

@implementation HumanContact {

@synthesize firstName, surname, telephoneNumber;

// all default init + dealloc methods etc (remember to release the properties etc)
}
```

Now this object exists as a method of containing all data about a contact. It is the *Model* in your [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

Externally, when you parse your XML, instead of adding a key for each item in `NSUserDefaults`, for each record in the XML you would create a `HumanContact` object:

```
HumanContact *contact = [[HumanContact init] alloc];
```

and populate the member variables appropriately:

```
if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"telnumber"]) {

contact.firstName = currentElementValue;

}
//  etc for remaining attributes
```

This contact can then be added to a member variable (could be a single `HumanContact` or an array of them (more likely)).

Once you've parsed the XML you have a local representation of this information that can be accessed anywhere in the class (and passed to other classes very simply).

In your `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` you simply query your model for the information, instead of `NSUserDefaults`

i.e

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
HumanContact *curContact = [arrayOfContacts getItemAtIndex: indexPath.row];
cel.text = curContact.telephoneNumber;
//...
}
```

Hope this helps

**edit**

In your tableViewController (wherever you are parsing the xml) you need to have an array in the .h

```
@interface FooTableViewController
{
  NSMutableArray *books;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *books;
```

Then in the .m:

```
@synthesize books;
```

in `viewDidLoad`

```
self.books = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
```

where you parse your xml:

```
book.telNumber = currentElement;
[self.books addItem:book]; // array is of books, so add the whole thing
```

Then in your tableViewCell
    Book currentBook = [this.books objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    NSString *telNum = currentBook.telNumber;

Remember that you are adding the `Book` to the array, and you ger a book back from the array.

Comment: Seems my MVC link hasn't worked, so here is the intended link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller

Comment: i think i am not able to add them to array

if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"telnumber"]) {
   NSLog(@"telphne is = %@",aBook.telnumber);// working perfect


 // how to add them to arry??? 
  aBook.telnumber = currentElementValue;
  [appDelegate.books addObject:aBook.telnumber];
}


lets say i have abook as object name 


now i am using this in detail view

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


 
 
 NSLog(@"telphne is = %@",aBook.telnumber);/ Its NULL 

}

Comment: in table cell i am displaying values form bothfield  SQL and XML 

and aBook is storing all info

Comment: lets say i am not adding to array then can i access that object by some index????
if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"telenumber"]) {
  aBook.telnumber = currentElementValue;

  
  return;
    }


how to

Comment: thanks now lets say in detail view i have 5 fields  of which 1st 3 elements are called from SQL and last 2 elemnts are from xml (i am parsing that xml when user press any cell before going to detail view)

so i am using this
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
Book *aBook = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


but this book is having some value from SQl so what should i do as i cant append my XML value to book array
so what i did is i made a new array bookB
Book *aBook = [appDelegate.bookB objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: but either i can use Book *aBook = [appDelegate.bookB objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

or 
Book *aBook = [appDelegate.books objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

but not both :(

Comment: Can't you build the Book object with info from both SQL and XML?

Either build the Book with the xml values and add it to the array. Then when you get the SQL data, find the Book in the array and add the new data.  

so you parse xml and end up with an array of books, but they are missing the SQL data.  When you get the SQL data, get the book from the array and add the extra stuff.

from XML         book.telNumber = currentElement;
                 [self.books addItem:book];

then you get SQL
                Book *curBook = [books itemAtIndex:0];
                existingBook.title = sqlTitle

Comment: Thanks for your help but i am confused i wish my NSDefault will save me and will not make my app hang  .